# How to store the index key of the sorting value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the array by last value of the tab delimited data. 
My data like this

```
AEDAG       6   5   6 
AEDSG       8   5   3
AEEAP       10  5   12
AEEKP       77  5   2
AELKVT      5   6   12
```

I try to sort the data by last column(6,3,12,2,12) Expected output is

```
AELKVT      5   6   12
AEEAP       10  5   12
AEDAG       6   5   6 
AEDSG       8   5   3
AEEKP       77  5   2
```

I tried following script

```
var array = ["AEDAG     6   5   6","AEDSG       8   5   3","AEEAP       10  5   12","AEEKP      77  5   2","AELKVT      5   6   12"];
var index = [];
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var ech_line = array[i].split(/\t+/);
    index.push(i);
    data.push(ech_line[3]);
}

var sorted_index = [];

data.sort(function(a,b)
{ 
    var xac = b-a; 
    sorted_index.push(data.indexOf(xac)); //Here i push the value of sorted data.
    return xac;
});


var modified_data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sorted_index.length; i++)
{
    modified_data.push(sorted_index[i]);

}
```

What is my mistake. In my script. How can i do it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to work with `objects` instead of `space delimited data`? Or what i should call it.

Comment: Would it be OK for you to use 2D-Arrays? Like `array["AEDAG"] = [6,5,6]` ...

Comment: @CodeiSir I want to create the 2D-array Like this  ["AEDAG    6    5"] = [6]

Comment: ["AEDAG 6 5"] = [6] is a object, not an array. also why would you want `[6]` instead of `6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming the tab separated values, I would suggest to change the way you do it a bit:

```
    var array = ["AEDAG 6   5   6","AEDSG   8   5   3","AEEAP   10  5   12","AEEKP  77  5   2","AELKVT  5   6   12"];
    var data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
         var ech_line = array[i].split(/\t+/);
         data.push(ech_line); //Each data row is the tab separated values splited array
    }

    var data_sorted = data.sort(function(a,b)
    { 
        if(b[3]/1 > a[3]/1) //Define a custom comparision for sorting data
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1;

        return 0;
    });

var data_formated = data_sorted.map(function(item){
    return item[0]+"\t\t"+item[1]+"\t"+item[2]+"\t"+item[3];
});
    alert(data_formated); //Print the desired result.
```

I make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w9oqbsc/) to see that working.
Maybe you would need some format, but you had all the information needed and sorted.

Comment: Great. This is working fine. I want to output with  tab delimited data. Like a input.                 That the reason i iterating the while loop like `while(i < data_sorted.length) {   var spliI = (data_sorted[i].toString()).split(",");   global_output.push(spliI[0]+"\t\t"+spliI[1]+"\t"+spliI[2]+"\t"+spliI[3]);  }`. Without loop iterating how can i do it? Any possible way for to do this

Comment: Well, we could use `map` to do the conversion. I'll update the answer. UPDATED code answer and jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code: *please tell me if you need further clarification about how it works*

```js
var array = ["AEDAG\t6\t5\t6", "AEDSG\t8\t5\t3", "AEEAP\t10\t5\t12", "AEEKP\t77\t5\t2", "AELKVT\t5\t6\t12"];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.split(/\t+/)[3] - a.split(/\t+/)[3]
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not sort the original data.  I want the output is `AELKVT      5   6   12,AEEAP       10  5   12,AEDAG       6   5   6, AEDSG       8   5   3,AEEKP       77  5   2`?

Comment: Note that the spaces is for the markdown format (1 tab is 4 spaces) and maybe we are really talking about tabs in the OP question, but when you copy the code you see spaces instead.